# Столкновение "если... то" и "чтобы"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

Конструкция:

> Если вы заходите в подъезд, то чтобы увидеть ободранную дверь, вам
>   нужно будет повернуть голову вправо и вглядеться.

Предложение корявое, оно быстро сочинено, потому что я просто дублирую конструкцию, не могу привести оригинал. Суть в том, что сталкиваются "если... то" и "чтобы". Нужна ли запятая перед "чтобы" или "то чтобы" превращается в неделимую единицу без запятой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь получается интересный парадокс. Если не поставить запятую, то получается следующее:
*Если вы заходите в подъезд, то чтобы увидеть ободранную дверь.* || Заходите с целью увидеть эту дверь. Но следующая часть противоречит этому смыслу, поэтому ТО относится именно к ней. Из этого следует, что запятая обязательна.

Теоретически предложение может существовать и без запятой - в вышеуказанном смысле. Но тогда третья часть самостоятельна - не связана со второй, а смысл довольно абсурдный, совсем не тот, что задумывался.

Comment: Во! Вы обозначили то, что меня напрягало. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна, поскольку придаточное со *"чтобы"* можно перенести в конец предложения. При этом *"то"* не теряет своего смысла и остаётся необходимым: *если заходите, то вам нужно.*

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, да. Это похоже на сложноподчиненное предложение. Об этом говорит союз "чтобы".